# How to make custom header then image description belongs to that Header and same process is carry on in TableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, xcode, uitableview

I'm building a project for what i have to make a tableview in which i have to include the images of three groups with their names and positions.
**Groups are as follows: (1).OFFICE BEARERS (2).MEMBERS (3).CO-OPTED MEMBERS.**

***I want to make group as Heading and then want to show the images of the members which corresponds to that group with their NAME And DESIGNATION.Then another group as headings and images of the members which belongs to them. and so on. Sample Image is given below***

**Every group have many members so i want to use dynamic cells.**

What are the best practice to do that... Please help me

---

Note: Images are residing in my Project's assets. 
Image of tableview is like so..

---

[image]

Comment: This is a typical multi-section TableView design. You can specify a custom view for each of the section's header.

Comment: @DipankarDas no i donot want label but I want name of header in the middle and yes i want background color in section header..

Comment: @DipankarDas, Yes i have only three sections but every section have multiple members.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prepare a data structure, for example like this:

```
[ 
      {
         "name": "group name"
         "members": [{
                     "image":"member image"
                     "designation":"member image"
                   },
                   {
                     "image":"member image"
                     "designation":"member image"
                    }]
       },
      {
        "name": "group name"
        "members": [{
                     "image":"member image"
                     "designation":"member image"
                    },
                    {
                     "image":"member image"
                     "designation":"member image"
                   }]
     }
```

]

Parse this data structure into model objects shown below or you can use Dictionaries.
    class Group: NSObject {
        var name:String!
        var members:[Member]!
    }
    class Member: NSObject {
        var image:UIImage!
        var designation:String!
    }
and then use in your tableView as shown below

```
var groups:[Group]!
    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return groups.count
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return groups[section].members.count
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
        let group = groups[section] as Group
        return group.name
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell Identifier", for: indexPath)
        let member = groups[indexPath.section].members[indexPath.row]
        cell.imageView?.image = member.image
        cell.textLabel?.text = member.designation
        return cell
    }
```

Comment: thanx for this great answer. Because i'm a beginner in ios so i don't how to create such type of data structure so please tell me where and how i can make this Data structure.

Comment: There are multiple ways. If your data is static then simplest way for you to hard code it somewhere. Or if you want more flexibility then, You can use a plist file or prepare a JSON and store in a file, parse that plist or json file.

Comment: after making the deeply nested dictionary, my project is unable to build. After removing the dictionary it was build quickly. What can i do now

Answer (score 0):

`UITableView` supports headers and footers, using the `UITableViewdelegate` methods [tableView:HeightForHeaderInSection](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uitableviewdelegate/1614855-tableview?language=objc) and [tableView:viewForHeaderInSection](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uitableviewdelegate/1614901-tableview?language=objc) and make sure you populate your cells correctly by the `section`and `row`. The `indexPath.section` will tell which `header` the cell is under and the `indexPath.row` will tell which cell by order it is in that section.

Answer (score 0):

I create expand tableview , this may be help full for you

```
    class Order_History_ViewController: BASEVC,UITableViewDelegate ,UITableViewDataSource
     {
    @IBOutlet weak var tableview: UITableView!
    @IBOutlet weak var menu: UIButton!

var order : NSMutableArray = NSMutableArray()
var product : NSMutableArray = NSMutableArray()
var fruit1 = ["product_name":"Apple","unit":"500 gms","img":"fruit_apple.jpeg","price":"Rs.150","shop_name":"C.G.FOOD"]
var fruit2 = ["product_name":"Banana","unit":"12 pc","img":"fruit_banana.jpeg","price":"Rs.50","shop_name":"Fresh Supply"]
var fruit3 = ["product_name":"Cherry","unit":"250 gms","img":"fruit_cherry.jpeg","price":"Rs.60","shop_name":"C.G.FOOD"]
var fruit4 = ["product_name":"Grape","unit":"250 gms","img":"fruit_grape.jpeg","price":"Rs.30","shop_name":"C.G.FOOD"]
var fruit5 = ["product_name":"Mango","unit":"500 gms","img":"fruit_mango.jpeg","price":"Rs.100","shop_name":"Cayce Food"]
var order_date = ["Fri, March 11, 2016","Fri, March 04, 2016"]
var order_number = ["Order #246","Order #126"]
var price = ["Rs.390","Rs.330"]
var charge = ["Rs.50","Rs.50"]
var total = ["Rs.440","Rs.380"]
var Fees : Double = Double()
var btnHeaderTag : Int!
var upDownImageView : UIImageView = UIImageView()
var isImgChange : Bool = false

override func viewDidLoad()
{
    super.viewDidLoad()
    product.addObject(fruit1)
    product.addObject(fruit2)
    product.addObject(fruit3)
    product.addObject(fruit4)
    product.addObject(fruit5)
    let order1Dic : NSMutableDictionary = NSMutableDictionary()
    order1Dic["isExpandable"] = 0
    order1Dic["Data"] = product
    let order2Dic : NSMutableDictionary = NSMutableDictionary()
    order2Dic["isExpandable"] = 1
    order2Dic["Data"] = product
    order.addObject(order1Dic)
    order.addObject(order2Dic)
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning()
{
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat
{
    return 150
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView?
{
    let view = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.view.frame.width, height: 100))
    //Header view
    let headerView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.view.frame.width, height: 49))
    let OrderDate = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 10, y: 10, width: 150, height: 30))
    OrderDate.textColor = UIColor(red: 24/255, green: 24/255, blue: 24/255, alpha: 1)
    OrderDate.font = UIFont(name: "JosefinSans-Regular_0.ttf", size: 23)
    OrderDate.text = order_date[section]
    headerView.addSubview(OrderDate)
    headerView.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 198/255, green: 198/255, blue: 198/255, alpha: 1)
    upDownImageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: self.view.frame.width - 35, y: 23, width: 15, height: 10))
    upDownImageView.image = UIImage(named: "select_time_arrow")

    if self.btnHeaderTag != nil
    {
        if section == self.btnHeaderTag
        {
            if !self.isImgChange
            {
                upDownImageView.image = UIImage(named: "select_time_arrow")
            }
            else if self.isImgChange
            {
                upDownImageView.image = UIImage(named: "down_arrow")
            }
        }
    }

    headerView.addSubview(upDownImageView)
    let btn = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.view.frame.width, height: 49))
    btn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(Order_History_ViewController.onHeaderClick(_:)), forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
    btn.tag = section
    print(btn.tag)
    headerView.addSubview(btn)


    view.addSubview(headerView)

    return view
}

func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int
{
    return order.count
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int
{
    if btnHeaderTag != nil
    {
        if let isExpandable = self.order[btnHeaderTag].valueForKey(EXPANDABLE_KEY) as? Int
        {
            if section == btnHeaderTag
            {
                if isExpandable == 1
                {
                    // product details
                    if let _ = self.order[btnHeaderTag].valueForKey("Data") as? NSMutableArray
                    {
                        return product.count
                    }
                }
                else if isExpandable == 0
                {
                    return 0
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return 0
 }

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
{
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("history_cell", forIndexPath: indexPath)as!Cart_TableView_Cell
    let dataDict : NSDictionary = product[indexPath.row] as! NSDictionary

    cell.lblProduct_Name.text = dataDict["product_name"] as? String
    cell.lblShop_Name.text = dataDict["shop_name"] as? String
    cell.lblUnit.text =  dataDict["unit"] as? String
    cell.lblPrice.text = dataDict["price"] as? String
    let img = dataDict["img"] as? String
    cell.img_Product.image = UIImage(named:img!)

    return cell
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath)
{
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didDeselectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath)
{

}

func onHeaderClick(button : UIButton)
{
    print("click")
    btnHeaderTag = button.tag
    print(btnHeaderTag)

    for (index,value) in self.order.enumerate()
    {
        if index == btnHeaderTag
        {
            if let isExpandable = value.valueForKey(EXPANDABLE_KEY) as? Int
            {
                if isExpandable == 0
                {
                    value.setValue(1, forKey: EXPANDABLE_KEY)
                    self.isImgChange = true
                }
                else
                {
                    value.setValue(0, forKey: EXPANDABLE_KEY)
                    self.isImgChange = false
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            value.setValue(0, forKey: EXPANDABLE_KEY)
        }
    }
    self.tableview.reloadData()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the sample code:

```
-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView{
return 4;
}

-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{

if (section==0)
    return 5;
else
    return 3;

}


-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section{
return 60.0f;
}

-(nullable UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    UIView *view1=[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, 20.0f, tableView.bounds.size.width, 60.0f)];

    view1.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];

    UILabel *label=[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, 20.0f, tableView.bounds.size.width, 40.0f)];
    label.text=@"  Appointment";
    label.textColor=[UIColor whiteColor];
    label.backgroundColor=[UIColor colorWithRed:1.0f/255.0f green:67.0/255.0f blue:102.0f/255.0f alpha:1];
    label.textAlignment=NSTextAlignmentLeft;
    label.numberOfLines=0;
    [view1 addSubview:label];
    return view1;
 }
 -(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{


static NSString *identifier=@"BOOKINGDETAILS";

BookingDetailsTableViewCell *cell=[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:identifier];

if (cell==nil) {

    cell=[[BookingDetailsTableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:identifier];
}

    cell.lblStatic.text=[arrStatic objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.lblresult.text=[arrData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

cell.selectionStyle=UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;

return cell;

}
```